# Why - Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, tomcat, mod-jk

I am using apache2 + mod_jk(ajp protocol) + tomcat7.

but I always get the error below:

```
[Sat Mar 30 17:30:54.691 2013] [25238:3074365824] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Sat Mar 30 17:30:54.691 2013] [25238:3074365824] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing.
[Sat Mar 30 17:30:54.691 2013] [25238:3074365824] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-status' in uri map post processing.
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you need the tomcat admin package (for me, it's tomcat6-admin) to provide `jk-manager` and `jk-status`. After installing that, you just need to configure these two items in your `workers.properties` file.

If you can't find `workers.properties` file, have a look at your apache config, for example: `grep -r JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2`. The config should contain something like the following, which indicates the path of the `workers.properties` file:

```
<IfModule jk_module>
    JkWorkersFile /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties
    # ...
</IfModule>
```

**In your `workers.properties` file:**

Make sure you have the following or something like it:

```
# configure jk-status
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true
# configure jk-manager
worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your `workers.properties` for unwanted special characters by opening the file, for instance in notepad, as it is advised here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666649/apache-httpd-2-2-x-mod-jk-1-2-30-tomcat-6-error-could-not-find-worker-with).